# Java beginner -Trying to let player quit the game

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I'm a beginner making a guessing game and I am trying to let the player quit the game by making their guess -1. Currently, if I enter -1 it says Too low and asks me to keep guessing and the player cannot quit the game until they guess the number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice;
    
    do {
        int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        int guess = 0;

        while (guess != randomNum) {

            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1-100");
            guess = scan.nextInt();

            if (guess > randoomNum) {
                System.out.println("Too high.");
            }
            else if (guess < randoomNum) {
                System.out.println("Too low.");
            }
            else if (guess > 0) {
                System.exit(0);
                System.out.println("GAME OVER");
                System.out.println("the number was " + randomNum + ".");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Correct! Well done!");
            }
        }
    
        System.out.println("\nPlay again? (Y/N)");
        choice = scan.next() .charAt(0);

    
    } while (choice == 'Y' | choice =='y');

    
    System.out.println("GAME OVER");
}
```

Comment: Right after `guess = scan.nextInt();` add `if (guess == -1) break;`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, it seems it should break out the nested loop, or possibly, `System.exit()` may be used

Comment: @AlexRudenko Ok. Then they should move the stuff in the `else if (guess > 0)` block to where I have `break`. So, really just move that whole block up to right after they get the user input. It should have been `else if (guess < 0)` anyway. Typo?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you!

Comment: In the final while, you should use a logical or ("||") rather than the bit wise or.

Answer (score 1):

The existing code needs to be modified slightly: the condition with exit should be checked before comparing to the `randomNum`.

Other issues to be addressed:

- Use `input` for `Scanner` instance
- Perform `System.exit` *after* printing goodbye message

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char choice;
    
do {
    int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    int guess = 0;

    while (guess != randomNum) {

        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1-100, or -1 to exit");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        
        if (guess == -1) {
            System.out.println("GAME OVER");
            System.out.println("the number was " + randomNum + ".");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (guess > randomNum) {
            System.out.println("Too high.");
        }
        else if (guess < randomNum) {
            System.out.println("Too low.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Correct! Well done!");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nPlay again? (Y/N)");
    choice = input.next().charAt(0);

} while (choice == 'Y' || choice =='y');
   
System.out.println("GAME OVER");
```